# Cauchy problem for the heat equation in Fourier space

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, heat-equation, cauchy-problem

I'm trying to understand how to work with heat equations and I'm stuck on a step that is probably very basic.

We have the Cauchy problem$$u_t- \Delta u=0, (x,t)\in R^n \times R_+ $$ $$u(x,0)=g(x), x \in R^n$$

I understand the initial part, aka Fourier transform. We assume that the time derivative doesn't affect it. Furthermore, we consider that $F[{d^nu \over dx^n}]=(i\xi)^n \hat u$, so what I end up with is $${\partial \over \partial t} \hat u(\xi,t)+|\xi|^2 \hat u(\xi,t)=0$$ $$\hat u(\xi,0)=\hat g(\xi)$$
What leaves me hanging is that at this point my book concludes with "thus $\hat u(\xi,t)=\hat g(\xi)e^{-|\xi|^2t}$ ".

I can see that it is right, what I can't see is how to get to that expression. 
Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure why but for some reason I just couldn't see that that's just a simple ODE. Go figure what went blackout in my brain... thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new equation is now an ODE in time for each $\xi$. Hint: What is the solution to
$$ y'(t) = -ky(t)$$
$$ y(0) = a$$
where $k,a$ are constants?

Comment: Yeah... not sure why but I was 100% convinced I could only work with $\xi$ since I had determined that the time derivative doesn't affect the transform. Don't ask me why, I don't know either... thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \hat u'(\xi,t)+|\xi|^2 \hat u(\xi,t)=0$$
This equaation is separable:
$$ \frac {\hat u'(\xi,t)}{\hat u(\xi,t)}=-|\xi|^2 $$
$$ \left (\ln {\hat u(\xi,t)} \right )'=-|\xi|^2 $$
Integrate:
$$ \left (\ln {\hat u(\xi,t)}\right )=-\int |\xi|^2dt $$
$$ \left (\ln {\hat u(\xi,t)}\right )=- |\xi|^2t+K(\xi) $$
$$ \hat u(\xi,t) =e^{- |\xi|^2t+K(\xi) }$$
$$ \hat u(\xi,t) =C(\xi) e^{- |\xi|^2t}$$
Since we have that:
$$\hat u(\xi,0)=\hat g(\xi) \implies C(\xi) =\hat u(\xi,0) =\hat g(\xi)  $$
Finally:
$$ \boxed{\hat u(\xi,t) =\hat g(\xi) e^{- |\xi|^2t}}$$